# Passing Props to children, children is not a function

Tags: reactjs, preact

`Test.jsx`

```
function Parent({ children }) {
    return <div>{children("Test")}</div>
}

function Test() {
    return (
      <Parent>
        { test => <div>{test}></div> }
      </Parent>
    )
}
```

Get an error saying `children is not a function`, But I see other examples on the internet saying this works. Anyone know why? On Preact X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this one?

```
function Test() {
    return (
      <Parent children={test => <div>{test}></div>}/>
    )
}
```